# LINQ query to Entity List within a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities, `Services` and `Facilities`. I have a `List<int>` with the ID's of the selected facilities and I need to retrieve the services for each facility.

I tried this

```
 Dictionary<int, List<Service>> Dic = new Dictionary<int, List<Service>>();

        foreach (var id in facilities)
        {
            Dic.Add(id,  _context.Services.Where(x => x.Facilities.Where(y => y.Id == id)));
        }
```

But all I got was this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to 'bool'

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But, why not start with the `Falicities`:

```
var Dic= _context.Facilities.Where(f=>facilities.Contains(f.Id))
                            .ToDictionary(f=>f.Id,f.Services.ToList());
```

Comment: Best answer, really, there is then a `Services` navigation property on each `Facility`)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Dictionary<int, List<Service>> Dic = new Dictionary<int, List<Service>>();

    foreach (var id in facilities)
    {
        Dic.Add(id,  _context.Services.Where(x => x.Facilities.Any(y => y.Id == id)).ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest do not make the SQL requests within a loop. Better select all `Services`, which contain your `Facilities`, and then map them to a `Dictionary<id,List<Service>`

```
 var services = _ctx
    .Services 
    .Where(x => x.Facilities.Select(y => y.Id).Intersect(facilities).Any())
    .ToList();

facilities
    .Select(id => new { 
        Id = id, 
        Services = services.Where(service => service.Facilities.Any(y => y.Id == id)).ToList()
    })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Services);
```